# How do I implement a customer wallet with Node.js and Stripe or Braintree

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, braintree, stripe-connect

I'm building an uber-like app where there are customers, and drivers:

1. Customers need to have a wallet to which they can add money using credit cards
2. Drivers need to be paid when they complete a ride, and my platform receives a commission on each ride fare.

I experimented with Stripe, but they don't seem to support a customer wallet implementation out of the box. Neither does braintree. Am I missing something?

Comment: you will have to set up a bank account with a bank to connect to, or find a service that has built in bank accounts

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Happy to offer help!

> Customers need to have a wallet to which they can add money using
>   credit cards

Braintree has a Vault in which you can allow customers to store payment methods, but there is no feature which will allow them to "add money".  These payment methods are represented as payment method tokens which can be charged at any point.

> Drivers need to be paid when they complete a ride, and my platform
>   receives a commission on each ride fare.

Braintree offers a Marketplace solution that allows you to split a payment to two parties; one being a sub-merchant (in your case, a driver), and a service see being sent to you, as the master merchant.  You can read more about Marketplace [at this link](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/overview).

Feel free to reach out to [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) if you need further clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Stripe doesn't support a 'wallet' style approach, but you can definitely use [Connect to build this](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/on-demand-app), though you'd then charge your customers at the time of purchase/use, rather than having them 'prefill' a wallet.

I'd suggest you [reach out to Support](https://support.stripe.com/email/login) if you have further questions on this one.

Comment: Thanks. The pre-filled wallet is a requirement though.